# What is the significance behind naming the series 'Moving'?

Tags: title, moving

In the Korean drama series 'Moving' (무빙), which centers around superpowered individuals who once worked for the government and are now in retirement or hiding, with their children inheriting their abilities and the government pursuing them for use.

What is the significance or reasoning behind choosing the name 'Moving' for the series?

P.S.: In the Korean language, the title of the drama is written as '무빙'.

Comment: The show is named after the webcomic that it's based on. Hence why it's named that.

Answer (score 2):

The show is based on a webcomic by Kang Pool of the [same name](https://tapas.io/series/moving-comic/info). One of the key topics of discussion by the parents of young Bongseok (a small boy with the power to float through the air) is whether they can afford to move to Seoul, a long-held dream of the mother. They discuss 'moving' on practically every panel for the first couple of episodes.

[image]

Obviously there's also a bunch of double- and triple-meanings here. The situation is emotionally fraught and Bongseok is capable of floating, which is an unconventional form of moving.